# Why the keyboard is overing the Edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a layout for ldpi with some elements inside a scrowview.
I have two edittexts and when I click one of then, the keyboard 
is overriding the edittext. Its haoening only in this screen and only in
this size of screnn. I have others layouts files with edittexts and It happens 
only in this layout.

This is the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".NovoCheckinActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="67dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.03"
    android:background="@drawable/header"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgVoltaNovoCheckin"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bt_back" 
            android:onClick="voltaNovoCheckin"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelAutenticacaoNovoCheckin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgVoltaNovoCheckin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgVoltaNovoCheckin"
            android:text="Novo Check-in"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvEventoClienteNovoCheckin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgVoltaNovoCheckin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgVoltaNovoCheckin"
            android:text="Reuniao - Porto Seguro"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="380dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="410dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.03" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelTipoCheckin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Tipo:"
            android:textColor="#333333" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btTipoCheckin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/labelTipoCheckin"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/borda_botao"
            android:hint="Chegada/Saída/Presença" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btLocal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/labelLocal"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/borda_botao"
            android:hint="Empresa/Cliente/Minha Casa" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etObservacoesNovoCheckin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/labelObservacoes"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/borda_botao"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" >                
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelLocal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/labelTipoCheckin"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btTipoCheckin"
            android:text="Local:"
            android:textColor="#333333" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etCustoNovoCheckin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/labelCustoNovoCheckin"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/borda_botao"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btSalvarNovoCheckin"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etCustoNovoCheckin"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.03"
            android:background="@drawable/bt_green"
            android:text="Salvar"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelObservacoes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/labelLocal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btLocal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Observações:"
            android:textColor="#333333" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelCustoNovoCheckin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btCheck"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btCheck"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Custo:"
            android:textColor="#333333" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/invisible"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/labelTipoCheckin"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btCheck"
            android:src="@drawable/invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/labelCustoNovoCheckin"
            android:text="Último Check-in do evento?"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btCheck"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/invisible"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etObservacoesNovoCheckin"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btunchecked" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the [activity android:windowSoftInputMode modes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) to help with your adjustment of items on screen

Comment: I tryed put this <activity "stateVisible|adjustResize" and "stateVisible|adjustPan" and did not worked.